# Why function not called on first click? [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, click

Why is the `toggleSidebar()` function not called on first click on the element, only on second etc.?

```
    $( ".image .image-inner .zoomer-holder" ).click(function() {

        var isDragging = false;

        $(".image .image-inner .zoomer-holder")
        .mousedown(function() {
            isDragging = false;
        })
        .mousemove(function(e) {
            isDragging = true;
        })
        .mouseup(function(e) {


            var wasDragging = isDragging;
            isDragging = false;

            if (!wasDragging) {
                console.log("TAP");

                // **** FUNCTION **** //
                toggleSidebar();    

                $(".image .image-inner .zoomer-holder").unbind("mouseup");  

            } else {
                console.log("DRAG");
                $(".image .image-inner .zoomer-holder").unbind("mouseup");  
                $(".image .image-inner .zoomer-holder").unbind("mousedown");
                $(".image .image-inner .zoomer-holder").unbind("mousemove");                            
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have your definitions nested, try moving the inner $().mousedown.. etc. calls out of the .click() function.

Comment: Sorry I´m new to jQuery: Yes, if I move it out, it´s called on first click, but on second click etc. it´s not called anymore... Thanks!

Comment: This could be because mousemove is being called and setting isDragging to true. Use the browser developer tools to put breakpoints on these events to see this, hope that helps